# Formatting columns in C++

Tags: c++

I have the following program that generates a multiplication table. A formatting problem arises when the outputs reach the double digits. How do I straighten out the columns?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std ;
int main() 
{
  while (1 != 2)
  {
    int column, row, c, r, co, ro; 

    cout << endl ;

    cout << "Enter the number of columns: " ;
    cin >> column ;
    cout << endl ;
    cout << "Enter the number of rows:    " ;
    cin >> row ;
    cout << endl ;

    int temp[column] ;
    c = 1 ; 
    r = 1 ; 
    for(ro = 1; ro < row ; ro ++ ){
      for(co = 1; co < column ; co ++ ){
            c = c ++ ;
            r = r ++ ;
            temp [c]= co * ro;

            cout << temp[c] << " ";
      }
      cout << endl ;
    }
    system("pause");  
  }
}
```

Comment: There's a big error in your program that will make it crash often: It should be `int temp[column*row]`. Additionaly, if you don't want to reuse the table, you can just do `cout << co * ro` inside the loop and remove the `temp` array.

Comment: I question why there's a temp at all. It's not used after the loop. Why not just do `cout << setw(3) << co * ro;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the [setw output manipulator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setw/):

cout << setw(3) << temp[c];

By default, this uses spaces to fill, which it looks like you want.

You will need to include iomanip as the documentation says.

Answer (score 3):

C++ had [`setw`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setw/) and [`setfill`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setfill/) for just this purpose. `setw` sets the width and `setfill` sets the fill character.

In your case, you can just use something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main (void) {
    std::cout << std::setw(5) << 7 << std::endl; // will output "    7".
    return 0;
}
```

---

You have a number of *other* problems with that code, at least some of which are listed below:

- You don't allocate enough space for your array, it should be `column*row` (or use a two-dimensional array).
- Array indexes start at 0, not 1.
- `c = c++` is not a good idea, `c++` will be enough to increment `c`.
- You may be trying to increment `c` twice in each iteration, once if the `for` statement itself and once in the `for` body.
- `system("pause");` is an ugly hack where the language provides a perfectly good `getchar` or `cin` equivalent.
- `while (1 != 2)` just looks plain *wrong* :-) since `1` will never equal `2`. Just use `while (1)` or `for(;;)` - any coder worth their salt will know what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

You can set width of your column elements by using stream manipulators like this:

`cout << setw(3) << temp[c]`

But this is something you need to fix besides: `c = c++;` does not increment the variable!

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those situations where the old-fashioned `printf` is a lot easier than `cout`. Replace `cout << temp[c] << " "` with `printf("%2d ", temp[c])`.

And I hope you've discovered the bug in your `c` calculation.

Comment: In the immortal words of Yoda when Luke tried to use C features in C++ after the crash on Dagobah: "No, try not. Do, or do not, there is no try." :-) Using `printf` may well be simpler than `cout` _for C coders_, but, if you want to be a C++ coder, use the full power of C++. Yes, I know `printf` will work, so will `#define` macros for code and constants - that doesn't necessarily make them a good idea. Again, not willing to downvote since I used this early on in my transition to C++ and it was a hell of a lot easier than trying to learn iostream/iomanip in its entirety in one day.

Comment: @paxdiablo, I know that printf is *way* out of fashion, and I have the -1 vote to prove it. I also know that it's a lot less type safe than the alternate. I still often find it to be the pragmatic approach, probably the only part of C that I still cling to.

Answer (score 1):

You could use "\t" instead of " ".

Comment: I'm not going to downvote this since it's useful in at least fairly limited circumstances. But, since it depends entirely on the terminal tabstop settings, it's not really suitable for production-quality code. If you don't control the tabstops, or if you output a number that crosses such a tabstop, your output will be munged.